# How to get the right path to a image in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have tried to use the code bellow, but Its not working:
('test' is my subtheme )

```
 $image = file_directory_path() . "/sites/all/themes/test/images/brasil.png";
```

Comment: What is the value of `$image` now?

Comment: @AmazingDreams that would be `.../sites/default/files/sites/all/themes/test/images/brasil.png`

Comment: @AmazingDreams Thanks, but your path is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### File path

D7:

```
$image = DRUPAL_ROOT . "/sites/all/themes/test/images/brasil.png";
```

D6 and D7:

```
$image = getcwd() . "/sites/all/themes/test/images/brasil.png";
```

#### File URL

D6 and D7

```
global $base_url;
$image = $base_url . "/sites/all/themes/test/images/brasil.png";
```

Comment: ./Applications/MAMP/web/drupal-drush/sites/all/themes/test/images/brasil.png

Comment: I believe you need the URL not the path in your server, see the edit

Comment: Thanks, the URL path seems to be OK, but Its not displaying an image.